# MSSQL's varchar(n) equivalent in GORM

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I would like to know if it's possible to set the size of VARCHAR column if database is MS SQL 2005. Here's my domain:

```
class UpdateTable {

    static mapping = {
        table 'UpdateTable'
        id column: 'UpdateFileId', generator: 'increment'
        version false
        fileName column: 'FileName', size: 50
    }

    String fileName
}
```

Note that it produces a 'FileName' column with VARCHAR(255). I would like to set it to just VARCHAR(25). Also tried this but it didn't work

```
static mapping = {
    ..
    fileName column: 'FileName', length: 50
}
```

Thanks for any leads on this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ok, i think i found the solution:

```
static constraints = {
    fileName(maxSize: 25)
}
```

found this in http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/How-to-map-String-to-something-larger-than-varchar-255-td1326146.html#a1326146

Answer (score 3):

The correct way to do it (or at least as the [documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Database%20Mapping/column.html) says) is:

```
static mapping = {
    fileName sqlType: 'varchar(25)'
}
```